# Getline error MFC vs2012 (msvcp110.dll)

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2012, getline

I have a problem to use the std::getline function in vs2012 with an MFC application. The same code was running in vs2010 that's why I am sure that it is not a problem with the code itself.

```cpp
void AddImage::OnClickedIdbAiRegistration(){
CFileDialog file(TRUE, NULL, NULL, OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT, "(*.dat)|*.dat||");
file.DoModal();
UpdateData();
m_ai_file=file.GetPathName();
UpdateData(FALSE);
std::string buf=m_ai_file;
if(filecnt(buf, "Dat")){
    std::ifstream file(buf);
    AfxMessageBox(buf.c_str());
    std::getline(file, buf);//Here is my problem
    AfxMessageBox(buf.c_str());
    file.close();
    }
}
```

The first AfxMessageBox returns the filepath (which is correct and a valid ASCII-file). The Second AfxMessageBox do i never reach because getline produces:

> Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEF7B4AAEE (msvcp110.dll) in program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

and vs11 redirect me to the xiosbase line 443

```cpp
    locale __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL getloc() const
    {   // get locale
    return (*_Ploc);/*THIS IS LINE 443*/
    }
```

For the project property i am using "Use MFC in a shared dll" and "Multi-threaded DLL" and Sub-System "Windows"

Additional program code and includes:

```cpp
#include <afxwin.h>
#include <afxframewndex.h>
#include <afxcmn.h>
#include <afxdialogex.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <regex>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <Windows.h>

usign namespace std;

class AddImage:public CDialog{
        DECLARE_DYNAMIC(AddImage)
    public:
        AddImage(CWnd* pParent = NULL);
        virtual ~AddImage();
        enum {IDD=IDD_ADD_IMAGE};
    protected:
        virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);
        DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    public:
        CString m_ai_file;
    };

AddImage::AddImage(CWnd* pParent):CDialog(AddImage::IDD, pParent){
    m_ai_file=_T("");
    }

AddImage::~AddImage(){
    }



bool filecnt(string path, string type){
    if(filepathcnt(path, type)){
        if(GetFileAttributes(path.c_str())==-1){
            return(FALSE);
            }
        else{
            return(TRUE);
            }
        }
    else{
        return(FALSE);
        }
    }

bool filepathcnt(string path, string type){
    if(type==""){
        tr1::regex regex("[[:print:]]+\\.[[:alnum:]]+");
        if(regex_match(path.begin(), path.end(), regex)){
            return(TRUE);
            }
        else{
            return(FALSE);
            }
        }
    else if(type=="-"){
        tr1::regex regex("[[:print:]]+");
        if(regex_match(path.begin(), path.end(), regex)){
            return(TRUE);
            }
        else{
            return(FALSE);
            }
        }
    else{
        string upper=type;
        string lower=type;
        transform(upper.begin(), upper.end(), upper.begin(), toupper);
        transform(lower.begin(), lower.end(), lower.begin(), tolower);
        tr1::regex norm_regex("[[:print:]]+\\."+type);
        tr1::regex upper_regex("[[:print:]]+\\."+upper);
        tr1::regex lower_regex("[[:print:]]+\\."+lower);
        if(regex_match(path.begin(), path.end(), upper_regex) || regex_match(path.begin(), path.end(), lower_regex) || regex_match(path.begin(), path.end(), norm_regex)){
            return(TRUE);
            }
        else{
            return(FALSE);
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyone an idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Did you clean the project and do a full rebuild, including of all dependent dlls?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it but it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem now by using VS10. There the algorithm works without any issues. But I do not think that this can be the solution!

That it works with vs10 on the same PC tells me also that it is not a problem with the PC.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a file object you should always make sure it's valid before trying to use it.

```
if (file.bad())
    AfxMessageBox("Bad file");
else
{ // existing code follows
```

P.S. You have two objects named `file` in the same block of code. Please don't do that, it's potentially confusing even if the compiler is able to keep it straight.

Comment: if have tried it but i still get the same error. It seams that he is acctually able to open it but not to read it.

Answer (score 0):

first Let us simplify the issue:

just hard code the path and running it in a new console project:(I added more protection code)

```
    String buf="the data file path";
    std::ifstream file(buf);
    if(!file.is_open())
        return FALSE;
    while(file.good())
    {
        cout << buf << endl;
        std::getline(file, buf);
        cout << buf << endl;
    }
    file.close();
```

what is the result?  if issue is still, your can set a debug point at the second cout << buf << endl to check if buf is assigned with a value.

You should also protect the FileDialog as following: or once click 'cancel', it will fail.

```
(dlg.DoModal()==IDOK)
  FilePathName=dlg.GetPathName();
  //....other opertiaon
}
```

Comment: A consol program works with the specified hard coded file path. But not in MFC.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not a good idea to write the line content in the string which contained the path to the file before. Try the following:

```
CString csFilePath("C:\\example.txt");
ifstream infile;
infile.open(csFilePath);

std::string strLine;
std::getline(infile, strLine);
```

By the way, did you copy and paste your code? As you wrote:

> usign namespace std;

instead of *using* namespace std;

Comment: If have added a new CString for the filename but it does not change anything.
The code was copied between vs10 and vs11 but the posted program code consists of many different files so that the `using namespace` line was handwritten.

Comment: As ifstream has no return value, you should check if the stream is good for i/o operations:
`if (!infile.good())
return;`
If the program returns at this point, you have to ensure that the file is writeable (Is the file opened while the tool is running? Do you have enough rights?)

Comment: I have added `if(file.bad())` as it written in the first answer. The file is not open anywhere else and i have the rights to edit it (i can write and append content).

Comment: `file.bad()` is not the same as `!file.good()`
Always use the second one, because it checks, as I already mentioned,  if the state of the stream is good for i/o operations. `bad()` only checks if the badbit is set.

Comment: yes it is good for i/o operations. now checked with `!file.good()` instead of `file.bad()`

Comment: Well this is strange. If the file is "good" but you still get a access violation error, there must be a problem with your system. I read that faulty RAM, or bad drivers can cause this problem. Check this site for more information: http://www.updatexp.com/0xC0000005.html

Comment: I have ported the whole project to a completly different PC (Win7 Enterprise to Win8 but both VS2012) and i still have the same error. I think the problems must be somewhere in the settings...

Answer (score 0):

It was working and is not anymore.

Change the compilation flag (in the project Properties > Configuration Properties > C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library) from `/MD` (multi-threaded DLL) to `/MDd` (multi-threaded debug DLL), for both Debug & Release configurations.

This should work in VisualStudio 2012 at least.

Comment: Can you please explain why this would help OP with their issue?

Comment: I don't know who OP is, but it might help B4DBOY as his problem bears significant similarities to the one I was plagued with, and which was thus solved.

Comment: "OP" means original poster, so I mean B4DB0Y when I say OP.

Comment: OK. Apologies. Now for the reasons of this working, it does entail the use of MSVCRTD.lib instead of MSVCRT.lib by the linker and its inclusion in the .obj file. Why it worked in VS10 and not any more in VS11 is probably to be found in the arcanes of Microsoft VS updates.